# After assigning a Map to ImmutableMap, how to stop or restrict reassign another map

Tags: java, collections, guava, immutability

I declared a ImmutableMap like

```
public static ImmutableMap<String, String> mapImmutable;
```

Assigned a map to this variable

```
mapImmutable= ImmutableMap.copyOf(map2);
```

Now if I assign other map to this 'mapImmutable' variable. It will not throw any exception and will update values.

```
mapImmutable=ImmutableMap.copyOf(map3);
```

public class UnmodifiedMap {

```
public static ImmutableMap<String, String> mapImmutable;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String,String> map2=new HashMap<String,String>();

    map2.put("name", "mark");
    mapImmutable= ImmutableMap.copyOf(map2);
    System.out.println(mapImmutable);

    Map<String,String> map3=new HashMap<String,String>();

    map3.put("Country", "USA");
    map3.put("name", "Joy");

            mapImmutable=ImmutableMap.copyOf(map3);\\It should throw an exception while reassign.
    System.out.println(mapImmutable);}}
```

Console Result -:
{name=mark}
{Country=USA}

It should throw an exception while reassign.

Comment: make `mapImmutable` final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
mapImmutable = ImmutableMap.copyOf(map3);
```

You are not actually changing the contents of the map that the field `mapImmutable` refers to. You are making `mapImmutable` refer to an entirely different map!

`ImmutableMap` being immutable doesn't mean that you can reset a variable of its type. It only means that instances of it will not change. e.g. you can't add new items to the map or remove items from it. In the above line, you are not modifying any instances of `ImmutableMap`, you are creating a *new* instance of `ImmutableMap` by calling `copyOf`, and assigning it to `mapImmutable`. The map that `mapImmutable` was referring to is not changed, but is simply *lost*.

If you want to disallow resetting a field, declare it as `final`, and set it in the static constructor:

```
public final static ImmutableMap<String, String> mapImmutable;

static {
    Map<String,String> map2=new HashMap<String,String>();

    map2.put("name", "mark");
    mapImmutable= ImmutableMap.copyOf(map2);
    System.out.println(mapImmutable);

    Map<String,String> map3=new HashMap<String,String>();

    map3.put("Country", "USA");
    map3.put("name", "Joy");

            mapImmutable=ImmutableMap.copyOf(map3); // now we have an error!
    System.out.println(mapImmutable);}
}
```

Also note that `final` only prevents resetting the field/variable, but does not prevent the object from being modified. If you have a `final HashMap`, you can still add KVPs to it.

Answer (score 3):

You should distinguish between the immutability of the `Map`, and the immutability of the `mapImmutable` field.

The `ImmutableMap` is, as the name suggests, immutable, however in your code, the field that points to the map is just a regular field. Therefore, it can be reassigned to point at a different map. If you want the field to be immutable, simply mark it `final`.